# nvm not found if I reopen the terminal on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, nvm

I ran the following commands to install NVM:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  
# This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

It works fine and I can run nvm without any issue but once I close and re-open the terminal it prompts with the following error:

> -bash: nvm: command not found

What is wrong?

MAC Version: 10.14.5

I have already node v11.13.0 installed.

Comment: You need to update your .bashrc or .bash_profile (depending on which one you uses) with the declaration of NVM_DIR you have above

Comment: @JoakimDanielson would you please elaborate more, I am new to Mac/Linux world.

Comment: The `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm` is only valid for the current session when you declare it like that. You need to add it to a configuration file so that the terminal app can read it whenever you open a new terminal. I suggest you look up a basic tutorial on bash, it is well worth it if you are going to be using the terminal

Comment: I just needed to run 'touch ~/.bash_profile' before installing, I found it in https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run `touch ~/.bash_profile` before installing nvm as mentioned in https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.